# Human Scale weapon but Kill-Scale Damage?

Tags: weapons, mekton

When scaling down <sup>1</sup> weapons get converted from Kill-scale (for Mech-to-Mech combat) to Hit-Scale (human-and-vehicle scale) using a multiplier of 2.5 for powerarmor and 5 for Roadstrikers <sup>2</sup>. The sidebar on page 108 offers to allow buying Kill-scale armor (which is not downscaled to Hits) for these, but there doesn't seem to be an option to get a Kill-scaled weapons for a human-scaled on that table. However, there are some human-carried Kill-scale weapons availeable <sup>3</sup>.

Do I miss an option that allows designing a small scale weapon that does damage in Kills?

---

1. <sub>Mekton Zeta Plus - Advanced Technical Manual pp.107</sub>
2. <sub>Mekton Zeta Plus - Advanced Technical Manual p.108 & 109</sub>
3. <sub>Mekton Zeta p.59</sub>